# Scalability of MySQL on Azure

Tags: mysql, performance, azure, scalability

I'm using a MySQL instance on Azure under the free trial period. One thing I've noticed is that `max_user_connections` is set to 4 under this option and 40 under the [highest priced tier](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/service/?name=cleardb).

Both of these seem really low, unless I'm misunderstanding something. Let's say I have 41 users making database requests simultaneously, wouldn't this cause a failure due to going over the max allowable connections? That doesn't seem like much room.

How can I use Azure to allow a realistic number of simultaneous connections? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly? Should I just dump MySQL for SQL Azure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the .NET framework, connection pooling is managed by the data provider. Instead of opening a connection and leaving it open for an entire session, with .NET each database operation/transaction typically opens the connection, performs a single task and then closes the connection after the operation completes. The .NET MySQL data provider also supports advanced connection pooling, see  http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/ComparingProviders.html

I would assume the Azure limitation is referring to applications that employ the first (session duration) alternative.

Comment: In my instance, I hit the connection limit of 4 simply on my development environment. I have a cloud service that connects periodically, a web site that connects on demand, MySQL Workbench that connects when I'm managing the database, and a Windows Store App that hits the database for various reasons. When I want to free my app to the world, the problem will exacerbate. My concern is that an exception will be thrown if no connections are available in the pool because of hundreds of simultaneous requests.

Comment: Do you know if the cloud and store app. use multiple connections? I would assume the store app. opens a single connection. If you can restrict the general audience to a single connection, you may only need five connections. But there sure are a lot of maybes to overcome.

Comment: Indeed. It just seems far too limiting to be of any use in a production setting.